# Best Practices for Efficiently Writing Time Series Data to MongoDB Collections with Dynamic Variables

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design

I am currently working on a project involving MongoDB with three collections: **datasources**, **variables**, and a time series collection **values**. The **values** collection stores time-stamped data for various variables associated with different datasources.

I would like to seek advice on best practices for efficiently writing and managing large volumes of time series data in the **values** collection, especially when dealing with dynamic changes in variables for a particular datasource.

**Collections Schema:-**

**Devices Collection:**

- Stores information about different datasources.

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("..."),
      "name": "Datasource Name",
      "description": "Description of the datasource"
    }
```

**Variables Collection:**

- Stores information about variables, including their names, descriptions, and units of measurement.

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("..."),
      "name": "Variable Name",
      "deviceId":ObjectId("...")  //Reference to the device
    }
```

**Values (Time Series) Collection:**

- Stores time-stamped values for variables associated with variables belonging to a datasource.

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("..."),
      "ts": ISODate("..."),           // Timestamp of the value
      "val": 123.45,                   // Actual value
      "metafield": {
        "variableId": ObjectId("..."),
      }
    }
```

**Estimated Volume of Data:**
Considering a scenario where there are **300 devices** sending messages **every 10 seconds**, the estimated volume of data per day can be calculated as follows:

Total messages per day = 6 * 1440 (6 times a minute * minutes in a day) * 300 (number of devices)

**Total messages per day = 2,592,000 messages/day**

**Specific Questions:**

1. **Efficient Data Write Strategies**: What are the recommended strategies for efficiently writing time series data to the values collection in MongoDB, especially when dealing with a substantial daily message volume?
2. **Handling Dynamic Changes in Variables:** How should I handle scenarios where variables associated with a datasource change dynamically over time? For example, if a new variable is introduced or if existing variables are modified, how can I ensure smooth data management in the **values & variables**  collection?

I am particularly interested in insights, best practices, and potential pitfalls that the community has encountered when working on similar projects. Any code snippets, architecture suggestions, or references to relevant MongoDB documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your valuable input!